# Git post-receive hook not firing on Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, git

I am trying to setup Git on my server so I can push my website changes. I am using [git-dot-aspx](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/06/25/hosting-a-git-server-under-iis7-on-windows/) and the push is working just fine. The problem is that the post-receive hook does not fire.

I renamed the file properly, double checked that it has execute permissions, searched for hours on Google, tested the post-receive script from the Git Bash successfully, and added an echo command to which returns nothing to the client doing the push so I am pretty sure that means the hook just never fires.

How can I get the post-receive hook to fire after I push to the server?